# Gridview link button click event - Windows application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to handle click event of the linkbutton in gridview in vb.net (windows application )

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to consume the DataGridView.CellClick Event and just check that you've got the correct column index. You can do it with the following steps:

> Create a new Windows Forms application
>
> Drag a DataGridView onto the screen
>
> In the design time properties, add a column to your grid of type DataGridViewLinkColumn
>
> Make the DataPropertyName property to "Link" (no quotes).
>
> In your forms constructor, paste this code under the call to InitializeComponent:

Oh yeah, you're doing it in VB.NET, so it would be:

```
Dim data As New DataTable()
data.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Link", Type.GetType("System.String")))
Dim newRow As DataRow = data.NewRow()
newRow("Link") = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
data.Rows.Add(newRow)
DataGridView1.DataSource = data
```

> Consume the DataGridView.CellClick event

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then
        Dim link As String = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(link)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Kudos for actually adding what everyone wants to do with the link.

Answer (score 1):

**Gridview Binding Time**

```
LetterB lb = new LetterB();
var letter = lb.GetLetter();
if (letter != null && letter.Count > 0)
{
     dgvLetter.DataSource = letter;
     DataGridViewLinkColumn lnkEdit = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();

     lnkEdit.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
     lnkEdit.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
     lnkEdit.HeaderText = "Edit";
     lnkEdit.Name = "SiteName";
     lnkEdit.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
     lnkEdit.TrackVisitedState = true;
     lnkEdit.Text = "Edit";
     lnkEdit.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
     dgvLetter.Columns.Add(lnkEdit);
}
```

**Click Event**

```
private void dgvLetter_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

     if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
     { 
          //your code
     }
}
```